# How to prove the intersection of cardinalities of 4 sets.

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove the following 2 affirmations and need some help:

1. $A \times B$ = $B \times A$ if only $A = B$ or $A \times B = \varnothing$

Proof: Assume $A = B$, then $A \times B = A \times A$ and $B \times A = A \times A$, therefore $A \times B = B \times A$ when $A = B$; if $A \times B = \varnothing$ then $A = \varnothing$ and $B = \varnothing$, so $A = B$. (this proof looks OK to me but I'm unsure if i should make it more in depth, if so how should i go about it?)

2. $(A \cap B) \times (C \cap D) = (A \times C) \cap (B \times D)$

(Struggling more with this one, no idea how to start, the first step just leads me writing the $(A \cap B) \times (C \cap D) = (A \times C) \cap (B \times D)$ again.)

Comment: Generally, to prove sets are equal, show that they are each subsets of one another.

Comment: "If $A\times B=\emptyset$ then $A=\emptyset$ and $B=\emptyset$" is incorrect; consider $A=\emptyset$ and $B$ equal to any nonempty set.

Comment: As for #2, to prove the two sets are equal you can prove the following two implications: "if $x\in(A\cap B)\times(C\cap D)$, then $x\in(A\times C)\cap(B\times D)$", and "if $x\in(A\times C)\cap(B\times D)$, then $x\in(A\cap B)\times(C\cap D)$". These statements have the advantage that their first halves give you some information about $x$ to work with.

Comment: #1,  You proved A = B or A×B is empty implies A×B = B×A.  The problem is asking you to prove the other direction.